# Fourier Transform of $f(t,\tau, N) = \frac{1}{1 + \big(\frac{t}{\tau}\big)^{2N}}$ over $t$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals, fourier-transform

I am struggling with taking the Fourier Transform over $t$ of the following:

$$f(t,\tau, N) = \frac{1}{1 + \big(\frac{t}{\tau}\big)^{2N}}$$

Since $\tau$ and $N$ are fixed, I can rewrite this as:

$$f(t,\tau, N) = \frac{\tau^{2N}}{\tau^{2N} + t^{2N}}$$

Letting $a = \tau^{2N}$, this gives:

$$f(t,a) = \frac{a}{a + t^{2N}}$$

So our Fourier Integral looks like:

$$ F(\omega, a) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{a}{a + t^{2N}} e^{-j \omega t} dt  $$

Now a handy table of Fourier pairs gives us:

$$ \frac{1}{2} e^{-a |t|} < -- > \frac{a}{a^{2} + \omega^{2}}  $$

So if I multiply the integrand by $\frac{1}{a}$ I will get:

$$\frac{1}{a} \cdot \frac{a}{a + t^{2N}} = \frac{a}{a^{2} + \Big(\frac{t^{N}}{a^{\frac{1}{N}}}\Big)^{2}} $$

Does this mean:

$$ \frac{a}{a^{2} + \Big(\frac{t^{N}}{a^{\frac{1}{N}}}\Big)} <--> \frac{1}{2} e^{-a^{N} |\omega^{\frac{1}{N}}|} $$

So that:

$$  \frac{a}{a + t^{2N}} <--> \frac{a}{2} e^{-a^{N} |\omega^{\frac{1}{N}}|} $$

If not, how can I evaluate this integral? What is the fourier transform?

Comment: @AhmadBazzi I figured, but I am not sure what to do then....

Comment: Nice work. But you have got $t^{2N} $ not $t^2$. So you can not use (directly) what you found from the Fourier table. Even for $N=1$, you have found a frequency domained function of your time domain function. You have to use a property to flip it. I guess the property is something like if $f(t)->F(w)$ then $F(t)->f(-w)$ but it won't matter here cause you got an absolute value.

Comment: Use contour integration to evaluate this FT.

Comment: @MarkViola I was afraid someone was going to say that. Complex contour integration is not something I am familiar with.

Comment: The above reasoning is incorrect. See the solution at the link below for the case $\tau=1$ and $N=2$. 


http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fourier%20transform%20of%201%2F(1%2Bt%5E4)